# Rich text - add additional insert types to ribbon

Tags: 2010, ribbon, rich-text, richhtmlfield

We have a requirement to insert new types of custom objects (for the sake of discussion, let's say a video) into the rich text area:

[image]

1. How do we customize this part of the ribbon for the Rich Text context?
2. Once the ribbon element is there, how does it insert a new object into the RTE area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Chris' Obrien's blog post for adding items to an existing group.

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/adding-ribbon-items-into-existing.html